# How to write generic unit testing for Swift 4?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift4

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my app (ios11, swift4, Xcode9), but all of the videos that I've seen are all too specific to the projects that the instructor is making and I'm having trouble converting it to my own classes and methods.

Can anyone please help me with some generic code that can be adapted to work in most situations? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't believe there's a unit test that works in most situations. Every unit test is highly specific to the thing it's testing (that's a key aspect of good unit tests IMO; they shouldn't be generic). You may want to give an example of the kind of thing you're trying to test and we can go from there.

Comment: There are several methods to do with a wide range of functions. Including core data, JSON connection and parsing, creation and usage of structs, basically everything to do with swift 4.

Comment: Are you having trouble testing JSON parsing? You write the JSON as a string variable (use the triple-quote syntax), parse it, and call XCTestAssertEqual to make sure it is what you expected it to be. What kind of generic code do you have in mind beyond that? Core Data is the same, as is creating structs. Could you give an example of code where you'e found the code difficult and expect that there is an existing and generic solution? I believe my problem is that I'm not picturing the kind of answer you have in mind. Is there a simple test subject where you know an answer & could give an example?

Comment: See, that's the thing. I don't even know what XCTestAssertEqual is. I'm looking for generic methods to test everything. I'm sorry if that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the confusion in the comments; when you said you'd seen tutorials, I'd assumed you'd been introduced to [XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest). The Test Assertions section provides documentation on all the assertions (like `XCTestAssertEqual`). You'll also want to read the rest of the pages there on things like async and UI tests.